# jQuery / deferreds : being notifyed when multiple .get are finished

Tags: jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

I've written this code in order to fetch items from multiple url's . I want to know when all of the `$.get` calls have been satisfied :

```
foo : function(arrIds){
    var arrJqxhr = [];
    var arrReturnedData = []
    for ( var i = 0, l = arrIds.length; i < l; i++ ) {
        var url = '/thing/' + arrIds[i].toString()
        arrJqxhr[i] = $.get(url)
            .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                arrReturnedData.push(data);
            })
    }
```

Apart from keeping count of how many times the `.done` has been called is there any better way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$.when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

```
 var arrReturnedData = [];
 var arrJqxhr = $.map(arrIds, function (id) {
     var url = '/thing/' + id.toString()
     return $.get(url)
         .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
         arrReturnedData.push(data);
     })
 });

$.when.apply($, arrJqxhr).then(function(){
    //this will be called once all requests are successfully completed
    $.each(arguments, function(i, arr){
        arrReturnedData.push(arr[0])
    });
});
```